# Update tabbed page content with Xamarin MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

so I'm using MVVM and for some reason when I create a main page which is the tabbed one, and add the children which are going to be the content pages, when switching trough tabs, they won't show any content whatsoever. Do I need some sort of InotifyPropertyChanged? Because I don't think the view model is aware that i'm on it.

This is my tabbed page xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:MvxTabbedPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Core.Pages"
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Test.Core.ViewModels;assembly=Test.Core"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:TypeArguments="viewModels:MainPageViewModel"
    x:Class="Test.Core.Pages.MainPage">


    <local:BudgetPage Title="Budget" Icon=""/>
    <local:DeliveryPage Title="Delivery" Icon=""/>

</d:MvxTabbedPage>
```

This is one of the content pages xaml (Budget):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:MvxContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:d="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Core.Pages"
    xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Bindings;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
    xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:Test.Core.ViewModels;assembly=Test.Core"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:TypeArguments="viewModels:BudgetViewModel"
    x:Class="Test.Core.Pages.BudgetPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
                <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical">
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

                <!--FEES
                -->
                <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Fees"/>

                    <Frame><Label mvx:Bi.nd="Text Gross"/></Frame>

                    <Frame><Label mvx:Bi.nd="Text Realization"/></Frame>

                    <Frame><Label mvx:Bi.nd="Text Net"/></Frame>

                    <Frame><Label mvx:Bi.nd="Text TotalHours"/></Frame>

                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</d:MvxContentPage>
```

Regards

Comment: Please show the code you're using. This way we would basically be guessing.

Comment: My apologies mate, you right

Comment: I've added more. Not sure why you deleted your answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40187469/xamarin-form-tabbed-page-with-mvvmcross#40224294

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Children` property, seems you have inherited TabbedPage to create a custom tab page.

Your code should look like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<d:MvxTabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Core.Pages"
            x:Class="App.MvxTabbedPage">
    <MvxTabbedPage.Children>
        <local:BudgetPage Title="Budget" Icon=""/>
        <local:DeliveryPage Title="Delivery" Icon=""/>
    </MvxTabbedPage.Children>
</d:MvxTabbedPage >
```

Comment: I’ve tried that today and it didn’t work. I’ll try the suggestion of the other post tomorrow and I’ll let you know. Thanks